# Flink on YARN with HA enabled crashes all RMs on attempt restoration

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to make Flink (1.2.0) work on our Hadoop cluster (CDH 5.10.0) with HA enabled but when I test it out by killing the active RM it brings down the entire cluster.

I have configured Flink's HA in `flink-conf.yml`:

```
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.storageDir: hdfs:///tmp/flink/recovery
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
high-availability.zookeeper.path.namespace: /cluster1
yarn.application-attempts: 2
```

I then run a flink session using `yarn-session.sh -n 2 -nm "Flink HA test"`

When I try to kill the active RM using `kill -9`, YARN correctly switches to the standby RM and I can see applications as `ACCEPTED` for a minute but soon the standby RM crashes throwing the following exception:

```
2017-03-08 12:29:36,997 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error in handling event type APP_ATTEMPT_ADDED to the scheduler
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerApplicationAttempt.transferStateFromPreviousAttempt(SchedulerApplicationAttempt.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler.addApplicationAttempt(FairScheduler.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler.handle(FairScheduler.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler.handle(FairScheduler.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$SchedulerEventDispatcher$EventProcessor.run(ResourceManager.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I do not configure Flink's HA the problem disappears.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Hmm it sounds like a problem with yarn rather than flink. I found a similar JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2823

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. Also found that issue but it seems to be fixed in Hadoop 2.6.0 (which is in CDH since 5.4.x).
I also found it strange that there is no mention of this issue specifically in combination with Flink as it can be reproduced consistently. I suspect misconfiguration on our part but I am not familiar with Hadoop enough.

Comment: Voted to close as this is about very old versions which have already gone out of support and is unlikely to be relevant for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments:

This was likely a yarn issue, caused by misconfiguration.

Given that the issue only occurred in very old versions (which are already out of support) it is likely not possible to add more detail.